# mariadb cluster gtid reset on machine restart

Tags: replication, mariadb, gtid

I'm trying to set up mariadb cluster replication, I directed slave to one of physical machines in cluster and everything works fine, but if I turn off that machine, and insert something from another machine in cluster and start it up again, it's gtid gets reset to 0-1-1, so replication fails.

what can I do?

Comment: still in bootstrap mode?

Comment: it was happening because of other problem, please check this and reply if you can help:
https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-8731